# Android gradle change file at build time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to change the content of a file at build time depending of a specific build type?

My app declares the following flavor:

```
flavorA {
        dimension "config"
        applicationIdSuffix '.flavorA'
        manifestPlaceholders.appName = "APP NAME"
        .....
}
```

For that flavor, besides `debug` and `release` I have two more build types: `debugClient` and `releaseClient`

For `releaseClient` I have to:

- Override `applicationIdSuffix` so that no suffix is added;
- In two files, `src/flavorA/res/values/values.xml` and `src/flavorA/google-services.json`, replace a string for another.

I saw an approach where we could use something like this:

```
task replaceToken(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/flavorA/res/values'
    into "$buildDir"
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['string that I want to replace': 'value that I need'])
}
```

but I'm unable to progress since it gives me an error.

How can I change the content of a file at build time for s specific build type?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to replace some String to another one during Build Time.

I created a new "*@EncryptedString*" Annotation using "Annotation Processor" of Java to choose which String should be encrypted and in which way.

Example:

```
class TestClass {
    @EncryptedString(passw: "abcd", hash: 2343, bypassWhileDebugging: false)
    private static final String = "my-personal-client-ID";
}
```

and during Build Time the class is transformed to (but I'm able to verify the output only by reverse engineering the final APK because the transformed Class is not shown in any way on Android Studio):

```
class TestClass {
    private static final String = "0093532-f9ab18-08b4-2776438895-f4";
}
```

It's not very easy especially while debugging initial Annotation creation...however it's very powerful and all the logic/alghorithms are not deployed in the APK but stay on Android Studio.

There are many things you have to read about:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder
- (from NetBeans but very helpful) https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/annotations-custom.html